# EV3 screen stuck at starting after inserting MicroSD card

Tags: ev3, pybricks

I followed the [official guide](https://education.lego.com/en-au/support/mindstorms-ev3/python-for-ev3) to download [microPython](https://le-www-live-s.legocdn.com/sc/media/files/ev3-micropython/ev3micropythonv100sdcardimage-4b8c8333736fafa1977ee7accbd3338f.zip) and flash it onto an empty MicroSD card (SanDisk Extreme Pro 32GB), but the EV3 screen is now stuck at "Starting" after I insert the MicroSD card. The EV3 works fine without a MicroSD card.

Comment: Hi Kevin and welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you please provide a link to this official guide you mentioned? That way it would be easier to talk about what steps were already completed, which might contribute to the problem and what should you do next.

Comment: @zovits Sure :) https://education.lego.com/en-au/support/mindstorms-ev3/python-for-ev3

Comment: So from your question I gather that you have an empty SD card within the spec (32GB, Class A1), downloaded the EV3 MicroPython micro SD card image from the linked site, flashed it using Etcher on Win10 or Mac, and now, after inserting it into the EV3 in the correct orientation, the brick does not boot. Is all of that correct?

Comment: @zovits Yes, and the brick keep sticking at Starting.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have edited the provided information into the question, so that others with an EV3 would have an easier time answering it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be due to a bad SD card or due to bad flashing software. For example, there was a broken version of the Etcher software in early 2019 that caused the same symptoms [[1](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/1270)].

Comment: Thank you and problem solved. Same reason as it was stated in Github.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add that I encountered the same problem today with Etcher version 1.18.11. I tried to flash the image on my SD card 4 times with this version. Each time Etcher validation failed, and when I tried the SD card in my EV3 the screen stuck at "Starting".

Then I installed Etcher version 1.5.26 and flashed again: validation was successfull this time, and the EV3 booted correctly with the SD card.

So the solution of using version 1.5.26 (https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/tag/v1.5.26) is still valid.

Comment: Indeed, etcher seems to have broken again for ev3dev images sometime before June 2023. https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/4079

Comment: Another alternative workaround is to extract the `.img` file from the `.zip` file and flash the `.img` file instead.